# Zorin OS 9-Booting from liveUSB error

Tags: mount, system-installation, live-usb

I am attempting to install the Ubuntu-based Zorin OS 9 via liveUSB. I have done a number of installs of Ubuntu based OS's but have run into a problem with this one.

I have created a liveUSB within my installation of Zorin OS 9 Core using three different applications...UNetBootin, the out-of-the-box Startup Disk Creator, and MintStick from the Linux Mint repositories. Now, you may ask how did I get it installed on the machine I'm using to begin with?!? I created a DVD using Brasero. The machine I'm going to install it on has no optical drive hence the need for a liveUSB.

When booting from the UNetbootin and Startup Disk Creator I get the following error:

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) stdin: Not a typewriter
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: No such device
Can not mount /dev/loop0(cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs on //filesystem.squashfs
```

When using a liveUSB made with MintStick the machine starts, I hit F9 for the boot menu, arrow down to select the USB drive, hit enter and the machine boots directly into the Ubuntu installation.

Extra specifics - both the machine using to create the live media and the target machine do not have any duel booting. One machine is an ASUS (target machine) and the other is a HP. When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the target machine the live media was created using MintStick installed within Xubuntu 14.10 and no issues.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted. **That** is the way solved issues are marked here, **not** by editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue.  I downloaded and installed Multisystem USB Creator and once I created a liveUSB with this tool I was able to boot into the live media and do an install of Zorin OS.

It seems as though the other live media creators for a USB we at fault in the creation of the media.  I'm not technical enough to explain why this is the case but I would guess it has something to do with Multisystem installing GRUB to the USB drive and then booting the live image from within GRUB.  If someone has more of a technical answer for this any and all comments would be appreciated.

Thanks for the feedback and help!  I will mark this answer as accepted as soon as I can.  When attempting right now it tells me I can tomorrow.